# How to retrieve an object into a new page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to select an object from a ListView `ItemClick` event and bring the contents of the object, in a new pages, so you can use the properties of the object. Now I have done so, it is right?

```
public void ListView_ItemClick_Citta(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Regioni NuovaCitta = (Regioni)e.ClickedItem;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CittaSelezionata));
}
```

How to retrieve the object in the new page? I guess I'll have to retrieve it in the method `OnNavigatedTo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the second overload of `Frame.Navigate(Type SourcePageType, object parameter)`

In your starting page...

```
public void ListView_ItemClick_Citta(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Regioni NuovaCitta = (Regioni)e.ClickedItem;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(CittaSelezionata), NuovaCitta);
}
```

In your navigated page...

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Regioni temp = e.Parameter as Regioni;

    if (temp != null)
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```